# PHP Sessions - Warnings

Tags: php, session, cookies

I asked the question "php warning - headers already sent after server move" yesterday and I have made changes since to try and fix the problem but im still not getting it!

I am working on code that has been made by another company! Im not moving the site off their server and putting it on ours but the my problem is that sessions are not working across the pages on the new server!

I am getting the warning:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/com10002/public_html/bank/index.php:28) in
>   /home/com10002/public_html/bank/includes/quickform.php on line 3

In my index.php

```
include('includes/functions.php');

$activeTab = "navhome"; 
$sent = false;

$title = (isset($_GET['title']))? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']) : 'Home';    
$title = str_replace('-',' ', $title);

if($title != '') {  

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM contents 
            WHERE name LIKE '%$title%'
            LIMIT 1";

    $result = @mysql_query($sql);       
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      
}

//Set page title
$pagetitle = (isset($row['name']) && $title != 'Home')? ucwords($row['name']) : "Bank Charges";
```

HTML..HEAD..META DATA AND TITLE TAGS..ECT

```
include('includes/header.php');

    <div class="textarea">
        <?php include('includes/rightcol.php'); ?>
        <div id="contentvideo" style="display:none;"></div>
        <h1><?=$row['h1'];?></h1>
        <h2><?=$row['h2'];?></h2>
        <?=$row['intro'];?> 

        <?php  include('includes/quickform.php');?>

        <?=$row['page_content'];?>          
    </div>

    <?php include('includes/subnav.php'); ?>
```

and in quickform.php

```
if($_POST) {
    session_start();
    $error = false; 
    $captcha = false;
    $sent = false;
etc.......
```

This is their code and currently works fine on the their server!

1) I have tried moving the `session_start()` to the top of `index.php`
2) Putting a session on both pages.
3) Removing white space before the session when it was in the index.php

My new version is the site is at `www.compensation-claims.org/bank`

Because this is not my code im not sure as to why they put the session in the quickform.php

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty fix would be to activate [`output_buffering`](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) on your server, by modifying your php.ini file *(and restarting Apache)*, setting something like this :

```
output_buffering=4096
```

The problem you have is because HTTP headers can't be sent if even only 1 character has already been sent ; by using that directive, you indicate that nothing should be sent before 4k of data have been buffered.

That's usually enough to buffer some white spaces that are present at the beginning/end of `.php` files, and are enough to cause that kind of trouble.

Note : this is a quick-and-dirty fix, but it might help you get the application working.

Of course, the best solution would be to remove any kind of output that is sent before calling session_start / or to move the call to `session_start` to the **beginning** of your PHP script.

One thing that often helps is to remove the closing `?>` tag at the end of `.php` files, so you don't have any white space after it, as it doesn't exist anymore *(yes, that's perfectly valid)*

---

**EDIT after having a second look at the given code :**

In `header.php` :

- You are doing some output (HTML code, like the div "textarea")
- And, only then, you are starting the session with `session_start`

  - as some output has already been sent to the browser, the `session_start` cannot create the cookie, and fails.

So, **you really need to move the session_start as high as possible** : but it right at the beginning of `index.php`, for instance ; or, maybe, to get it everywhere, at the top of `functions.php`...

... But definitly NOT in the middle of some HTML output!

*(What I said earlier about output_buffering is probably the reason why this (not good) code worked before)*

This should solve the problem, I think...

Good luck, anyway !

Comment: Thanks but it looks like my hosting dont let me edit the php.ini file!

Comment: Oh, too bad :-( Maybe using ob_start and the like, then ? Or you might have to go through every file, to remove un-wanted spaces, and stuff like that :-( 
As a sidenote : what is in index.php on line 28 ? You might want to look at that line, as it's the one causing the output, in this particular situation ;-)
Still ; one thing that should be not too hard to try : move the session_start as "high" as you can : it should be one of the FIRST thing done (so, put it at the beginning of the page that is called)

Comment: And i just edited my answer, to provide more informations ; and something that might be the solution to your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a UNIX character return is being sent to the browser because of how Windows handles carriage returns differently. One or more characters sent before sending headers will cause this error to occur. The alternative may be that the other server had output buffering enabled by a php.ini directive that was capturing and parsing any output before sending it to the client. This could have been the case for compression reasons. I would suggest comparing the php.ini configariton and seeing if gzip compression was enabled on the Apache server prior to the move.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ini_set() function in your script to set php.ini configuration values.

```
ini_set('output_buffering', 4096);
```